# Reducing the size of udev filesystem

Tags: 12.04, filesystem, ssd, udev

I have this line in the output of `df -h`:

```
udev             16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev
```

What is this thing doing? Do I need it, and if not, how can I reduce the size of it?

As far as I know, this never existed at least in Lucid.

Answer (score -1):

Udev handles devices in the new Ubuntu and it very much needed, check out this link for information on it's use: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/en/man7/udev.7.html

Comment: I don't think it needs 16GB.

Comment: Yea but why is it so huge?